# Question: Dividing values from two different Pandas Dataframes selected based on column values returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to select values from two different DataFrames based on certain column values and divide them with each other. If I try this I always get NaN values.

I added a simplified example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','c','d'],
                  'col2':['x1','x2','x3','x4'],
                   'col3':[10,3,2,8]})

print(df)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a1','b1','c1','d1'],
                  'col2':['y1','y1','y3','y4'],
                   'col3':[5,4,1,6]})

print(df1)

a = df.loc[((df['col1']=='a')&(df['col2']=='x1')),'col3']
print(a)

b = df1.loc[((df1['col1']=='d1')&(df1['col2']=='y4')), 'col3']
print(b)

c = a/b

print(c)
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Try ``a.div(b.array)`` or ``a / (b.array)``

Comment: `a` is extracting row 0 with value `10`, `b` is extracting row 3 with value `6`. When you're doing division, pandas is attempting to divide by the value in the matching row, but since `a` doesn't have a row 3 and `b` doesn't have a row 0, you get NaN for both rows.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is so powerful because it aligns on the indices when doing certain actions, for example mathematical methods.

If we print both `a` and `b` in your example, we can see that their indices are respectively `0` and `3`:

```
print(a.index)
print(b.index)

Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')
```

This means that when doing the operation `a/b`, pandas cannot align any values and thus returns `NaN`.

Your solution would be to `reset_index`:

```
a.reset_index(drop=True) / b.reset_index(drop=True)

0    1.666667
Name: col3, dtype: float64
```

Or cast to `numpy` arrays so we lose the indices:

```
a.to_numpy() / b.to_numpy()

array([1.66666667])
```

---

Having that said, your operation seems not really logical and the problem lies probably deeper. Since the matching of the values does not make any sense right now.

Comment: Thank you this is of great help, yes the real DataFrame I am using this on is much more complicated and I only tried to use a simple example. But your solution solved the issue!